# Two ViewController show the same Label Content

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iphone, class

I want to make two differed ViewControllers with different label content.
so I make this:

```
//the buttons
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labeltwo: UILabel!
```

```
//Content for the first ViewController

        @IBAction func randomword(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let yourDrink = ["Cola", "Fanta", "Water", "Sprite"]
        label.text = yourDrink.randomElement()
        
    }
    

//Content for the second ViewController

    @IBAction func randomWordtwo(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let yourFood = ["Pizza", "Appel", "Chees", "Hot Dogs"]
        labeltwo.text = yourFood.randomElement()
    }
```

one my firstViewController is see all from my first array all good.
but on my secondViewController I see the same array but I want to see the function "randomWordTwo" (the second array)

I have different Class for VC,labels and button. hope you can help me and thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your first view controller is not hidden and you are probably seeing your first view controller instead of the second viewController.

Hide your first viewController by `viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` .

Comment: I only have one ViewController.swift data that's right ? (im new sorry xD) and there I have the code for my Storyboard. Should I post a pic from my code view ?

Comment: the Class name is ViewController I only chance the Storyboard ID that's right ? every ViewController has the same class but a different Storyboard ID

Comment: to show view controller from storyboard, you need segue and please post your code.